# Integration test with ScalaTest and Future

Tags: scala, unit-testing, asynchronous, integration-testing, future

I'm trying to build my application around asynchronous method so I use Future with Scala. For more information, it's [elastic4s lib](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) in order to query an Elasticsearch server.

I begin with this pattern, so I first created this method:

```
    def insert(person: Person) = {
      client.execute {
        index into "index" / "type" source person
      } onComplete {
        case Success(s) => {
          logger.info("{} has been inserted successfully", interaction.toString)
          something_to_do()
         }
        case Failure(t) => logger.warn("An error has occured: {}", t.getMessage)
     }
   }
```

If I understand well, this method is not testable. 
When I read this [post](http://blog.abhinav.ca/blog/2014/09/08/unit-testing-futures-with-scalatest/), I have to create a method which returns a Future, and I have to use ScalaFutures (for ScalaTest) to test my async method.

So I execute this pattern, and I've created two method like this:

```
def insert(person: Person): Future[IndexResponse] = {
    client.execute {
        index into "index" / "type" source person
    }
}

def insertToEs(person: Person): Unit = {
    insert(person) onComplete {
        case Success(s) => {
            logger.info("{} has been inserted successfully", person.toString)
            something_to_do()
        }
        case Failure(t) => logger.warn("An error has occured: {}", t.getMessage)
    }
}
```

So now it's easy to test my first method, but how do I test the insertToEs method?

More generally, I would like to create integration tests: Kafka (embedded) to Elasticsearch (embedded).

I have this code which calls previous insertToEs method:

```
def receive: Unit = {
    ...
    val iterator = stream.iterator()
    while(iterator.hasNext) {
        insertToEs(iterator.next.message)
    }
}
```

I've created a test on receive method, but it looks like the integration test ends before the methods have been executed.

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ToEsSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with ScalaFutures {

  override def beforeAll = {
      run_kafka_server
      run_elasticsearch_server
  }

  override def afterAll = {
      shutdown
  }

  it should "receive message from kafka and insert to es" {

      send_to_kafka(json)

      receive

      assert if inserted in es
  }
}
```

Could you please advice me ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalatest.concurrent.Futures

In some of my testcase, I used : the following 2 patterns :

- with Future

  `val actualFuture = ...
  actualFuture.futureValue mustEqual ... //block until actualFuture isCompleted`
- with async, but no Future, I repeate test during a Time until success or timeout with http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually